# How to show popover for disabled checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have  checkbox list ,which contains one disabled checkbox.I want to display popover for this particular disabled checkbox.Currently it shows popover for all checked checkboxes.How can I achieve popover for disabled checked checkbox? Any help is appreciated.

**What I have done**

This is my checkbox div.

```
 <div class="fm-checkbox show-popover"  data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-content="User Can not change  your own Admin role.">

<input type="checkbox" checked id=@string.Concat("Role_",@Model.UserProfile.RoleSelectList[i].Value)  
class="i-checks"> <i></i> @Model.UserProfile.RoleSelectList[i].Text</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? You could use something like [Bootstrap 4's popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/) or [Bootstrap 3's popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#popovers).

Comment: Using the `title` attribute, doen't work for you? Normally it works on disabled elements just fine.

Comment: I made it possible to show a [popover](https://jsfiddle.net/zabftvce/) using Bootstrap 3. Only thing is it won't hide well, might be something for anyone out here to figure.